# "Concatenate" vs. "merge" vs. "join" in scientific text

Tags: differences, verbs, writing, computing

I wonder what the difference is between *concatenate*, *merge* and *join* from the lexical point of view.

These words are often used in scientific or programming text. It seems to me that different authors use any of them with slightly different meaning. How should they be used from the language point of view?

Comment: The exact technical definition of these words depends on the subarea of science or computation that is using them (some subareas may not have technical definitions for all these words). I'm not surprised that different authors use them with different meanings.

Comment: -1 Without specific examples to provide context, this question is just asking for dictionary definitions

Comment: Dear @PeterTaylor Thanks for voting me question down. I see questions on this forum must be very carefully considered as forum users vote them down if they not in their taste. The question ask about a difference between scientific and programming meaning of these words and they lexical meaning. The difference is not the same as dictionary definitions, (but maybe I am wrong in this point too). The question also point to usage of the words in scientific or programming text. I assume if I would copy large chunks of different texts, the question would be also marked down for lack of consistency.

Comment: It's not a matter of taste: it's a matter of whether there's a [specific question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) which isn't mere general reference (see [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#link-where-can-i-find-answers-to-simple-and-basic-questions)). Your comment seems to me to change the meaning of the question to something a bit more specific, but it's still quite vague: you appear to be asking for all technical meanings which three words might have in some field of science or IT. The answer to that is still "Find a good dictionary".

Comment: A good question might be "I've been reading a lot about relational databases recently, and the words *concatenate*, *merge*, and *join* seem to have a technical meaning. In these examples: (example 1) (example 2) I can't make any sense of them using the definitions in the Oxford English Dictionary or Merriam-Webster. Is there a good reference for database jargon which explains them?"

Comment: Dear @PeterTaylor I could spend night in library looking in different dictionaries but probably it would not resolve the issue. I asked here on the forum instead. I have quite a few very good answers which gives me some more insight into a 'living usage' of these words. How probably you already noticed I am not a native English speaker but I thought I used the best way to find an answer, and this way proved be correct. 

Your question is not as I meant, as I met the words over four years of study in England and there is rising confusion. I also can have perfect sense from dict def

Comment: Your question is not as I meant, as I met the words over four years of study in England and there is rising confusion. I also can have perfect sense from dictionary definitions and I do not seek explanation of the meaning but something else what I thought I clearly stated in my question. If I am wrong please advise where your miss understanding of my objectives coming from. I hope it help in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To me, concatenate refers to the very specific operation of appending things in order, specifically abstract things. Words and ideas can be concatenated, but things in the real world are usually not said to be concatenated. The word is mostly used in programming discussion and other discussion involving [strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28computer_science%29).

Merge usually implies mixing; if two companies, two ideas, or two galaxies are merged, they are implied to form one new entity in which the previous two are not distinguishable as wholes. It is more vague than concatenate.

Join can mean many things and it often depends on the context. If two organizations are joined, they may remain two organizations but under a larger name or cause or goal. Join seems to imply, sometimes, that there is something connecting two or more entities but those entities are still distinguishable. The word is a lot less specific on its own than the other two, though.

Comment: I'd say "concatenate" is a more specific form of "join". It's *not* a form of "merge".

Answer (score 6):

Consider the lists:

> ### List A
>
> alpha
>
> bravo
>
> charlie
>
> echo
>
> golf
>
> ### List B
>
> bravo
>
> foxtrot
>
> golf
>
> hotel

Concatenation would be appending one list to the end of the other, so concatenating List A to List B would result in:

> ### Concatenation
>
> alpha
>
> bravo
>
> charlie
>
> echo
>
> golf
>
> bravo
>
> foxtrot
>
> golf
>
> hotel

Merging refers to combining the two lists together, preserving their order.  Depending on the context it could keep only the unique records or preserve them.

> ### Merge
>
> alpha
>
> bravo
>
> charlie
>
> echo
>
> foxtrot
>
> golf
>
> hotel

Joining refers to keeping only the records common to both lists.

> ### Join
>
> bravo
>
> golf

Comment: The OP appears to be asking for the _lexical_ difference between the three words.

Comment: Introducing three words in the context of scientific or programming jargon, and then asking about the "language point of view" is pretty ambiguous, and I would also have assumed the question meant _their use in scientific or programming language_. Perhaps OP could clarify?

Comment: In what area of mathematics/science/computing does *joining* mean *taking the intersection*? In the areas of mathematics I'm familiar with, *join* means *union* (the same as what you're calling *merge*) and *meet* means *intersection*.

Comment: @PeterShor: In relational databases, joining is similar to (but not exactly) intersection.

Comment: After rereading the OPs question, I agree it is ambiguous.  I saw this: _used in scientific or programming text._ and also the [tag:computing] tag and figured thats what he meant.

Answer (score 3):

- [join](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/join): ***link***; connect:
- [concatenate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/concatenate?q=concatenate): ***link*** (things) together in a chain or series:
- [merge](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/merge): ***combine*** or cause to combine to form a single entity:
- [combine](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/combine): ***join*** or **merge** to form a single unit or substance
- [connect](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/connect): *bring together or into contact so that a real or notional **link** is established:*

In other words, *join* and *concatenate* **link** or *connect* things to form a chain or series. *Merge* and *combine* **unite** things to form a new entity where its original parts are indistinct. A *merge* could *coincidentally* also be a *join*.

Answer (score 2):

I only know *concatenate* from scientific contexts and I don’t think the word enjoys much day-to-day usage (though I’m happy to be corrected here).

*Merge* and, especially, *join* are more common in daily usage.  The difference between them, to my mind, is that things that merge generally lose their individual identity, whereas things that join do not (or need not).  For instance, if two rivers merge, it suggests that a new river is formed, but if one river joins another, then it suggests that one is a tributary and the other retains its identity.  Or consider herds: if two herds merge, then you can’t recover the original herds any more (maybe wildebeest do this); but herds of elephants may join together for a period then separate into their original groups.

Answer (score 1):

In most contexts, or as a broad generalization, the difference can be thought to be:

***concatenate***
Append or tag at the end in the order.
AA,BB -> AABB
Generally used with reference to two members; can be more.

***merge***
Combine together, with no regard to order/ position.
AA,BB,CC,DD -> could be (AACCBBDD / BBAADDCC /...)
Generally used with reference more than two members.

***join***
Place side by side/ end to end, with no regard to order/ position.
AA,BB -> could be (AABB / BBAA)
Can be thought of as *concatenate* without the order constraint.
Generally used with reference to two members; can be more.

The exact definitions do vary depending on the context (the field of application: math/ programming/ other) as @Peter Shor already stated above. However, as you seem to be only interested in the differences in a lexical sense/ context, the above may be of some help.